# Deserializing badly formatted dates as null in Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization, date-parsing

I have a Java web application which uses Jackson 2.x to deserialize JSON requests.  I'm currently interfacing with an external application which is sending JSON data with improperly formatted dates in one property of one of the classes.  This is causing exceptions with that client's calls (as well it should).  However, for business reasons we need a temporary workaround to accept these requests.

Until that client fixes the data it sends to my application (which may be a while), I want to treat any bad dates in that property as null.  I do not want to change the actual class itself, as it is a public API which exposed to other clients, and I don't want this temporary workaround included in that class.

Is there an easy way to configure Jackson to treat invalid dates as null?  I'm seeing similar functionality in [DeserializationFeature](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/DeserializationFeature.html), but nothing specifically for this.

Answer (score 1):

A solution that would require you overriding the setter of the original class in a subclass:

```
public class InvalidDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
            DeserializationContext deserializationcontext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss");
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        try {
            return sdf.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you would just need to annotate the overriden setter in your class with

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = InvalidDateDeserializer.class)
```

So the new DTO class would look like this:

```
public MyModel extends TheirModel {
    @Override
    @JsonDeserialize(using = InvalidDateDeserializer.class)
    public void setProblematicDate() {
        super.setProblematicDate();
    }
}
```

I understand this is no magic flag solution, but it should work in your case without changes to the original DTO class.